# Pandas cumsum with conditional product of lagged value?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm trying to get a cumulative sum that changes according to the product of another variable and the lagged value of the sum (sounds a bit like math gibberish, I know.. please bear with me)

Here's the example setup:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([1,1,1.004878,1,1.043394],columns=['xx'])
df['n'] = 1000000.0
```

Which assembles to:

```
       xx        n
0  1.000000  1000000
1  1.000000  1000000
2  1.004878  1000000
3  1.000000  1000000
4  1.043394  1000000
```

Now, we need to multiply the `xx` by the lagged value of `n`, iteratively, and then take the cumulative sum of this value:

```
cs = pd.Series([0.0] * len(df))
cs[0] = df.ix[0]['n']
for i,e in enumerate(df.iterrows()):
    if i == 0: continue
    cs[i] = df.ix[i]['xx'] * cs[(i - 1)]
```

This produces the following:

```
0    1000000.000000
1    1000000.000000
2    1004878.000000
3    1004878.000000
4    1048483.675932
dtype: float64
```

Question:  Is there a way to do this in pandas/numpy that doesn't require iterating over each row? If not, are there any tricks of the trade for optimising code like the above, when you are forced to iterate?  Can an creatively crafted index help in this case? Performance is a concern with 10000+ rows, across multiple datasets.

Comment: Use [shift](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your for loop can be simplified to:

```
for i in xrange(1, len(df)):
    cs[i] = df.ix[i]['xx'] * cs[(i - 1)]
```

*(more math gibberish)*
Each item in `cs[1:]` is the product of all *previous* items in `df['xx']` (the cumulative product) multiplied by the first item in the `n` column of `df`

```
>>> df
         xx        n
0  1.000000  1000000
1  1.000000  1000000
2  1.004878  1000000
3  1.000000  1000000
4  1.043394  1000000
>>> a = df['xx']
>>> a
0    1.000000
1    1.000000
2    1.004878
3    1.000000
4    1.043394
Name: xx, dtype: float64
>>> a = a.cumprod()
>>> a
0    1.000000
1    1.000000
2    1.004878
3    1.004878
4    1.048484
Name: xx, dtype: float64
>>> a = a * df['n'][0]
>>> a
0    1000000.000000
1    1000000.000000
2    1004878.000000
3    1004878.000000
4    1048483.675932
Name: xx, dtype: float64
>>> np.all(a == cs)
True
>>> 

a = df['xx'].cumprod() * df['n'][0]
```

This is not a trick.
This only works because `df['xx'][0]` is 1. If it was any other value, AND `cs[0] = df.ix[0]['n']` was not just a *shortcut* then `cumprod` wouldn't work.

Expanding each item of `cs` gives

```
cs[0] = df['n'][0]
cs[1] = df['xx'][1] * df['n'][0]
cs[2] = df['xx'][2] * df['xx'][1] * df['n'][0]
cs[3] = df['xx'][3] * df['xx'][2] * df['xx'][1] * df['n'][0]
cs[4] = df['xx'][4] * df['xx'][3] * df['xx'][2] * df['xx'][1] * df['n'][0]
```

Since `df['xx'][0]` equals one and `df['xx'][0] * df['n'][0] == df['n'][0]` then:

```
cs[0] = df['xx'][0] * df['n'][0]
cs[1] = df['xx'][1] * df['xx'][0] * df['n'][0]
cs[2] = df['xx'][2] * df['xx'][1] * df['xx'][0] * df['n'][0]
cs[3] = df['xx'][3] * df['xx'][2] * df['xx'][1] * df['xx'][0] * df['n'][0]
cs[4] = df['xx'][4] * df['xx'][3] * df['xx'][2] * df['xx'][1] * df['xx'][0] * df['n'][0]
```

**If You were to change the problem conditions slightly where after each iteration I need to subtract 0.05% of the last computed value of n (before the next iteration), does cumprod still work?**

If you did the *item expansion* exercise you should have seen that the new condition results in multiplication by the cumulative product of an array of the scaling factor.   Two ways to go about it - both result in some minor floating point errors from the calc performed in a loop.  Again, you need to account for the first item in `df['xx']` being one.

```
for i in xrange(1, len(df)):
    cs[i] = df.ix[i]['xx'] * (.9995 * cs[(i - 1)])

>>> k
array([ 1.    ,  0.9995,  0.9995,  0.9995,  0.9995])
>>> z = df['xx'] * k
>>> z
0    1.000000
1    0.999500
2    1.004376
3    0.999500
4    1.042872
Name: xx, dtype: float64
>>> z = z.cumprod() * df['n'][0]
>>> cs - z
0    0.000000e+00
1    0.000000e+00
2    0.000000e+00
3    0.000000e+00
4   -1.164153e-10
dtype: float64
>>> 
>>> z = df['xx'].cumprod() * df['n'][0]
>>> z *= k.cumprod()
>>> cs - z
0    0.000000e+00
1    0.000000e+00
2   -1.164153e-10
3    0.000000e+00
4    0.000000e+00
dtype: float64
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough explanation here.  If I was to change the problem conditions slightly where after each iteration I need to subtract 0.05% of the last computed value of n (before the next iteration), does cumprod still work?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the new calc.  Is it ```cs[i] = df.ix[i]['xx'] * (.995 * cs[(i - 1)])```? Subtracting .05% is the same as scaling by .995. See if you can *expand* each ```cs``` item using that factor (like I did above) - walk through the iterations *by-hand* and see if the ```cumprod``` pattern still exists. Then test it both ways - iterative and with ```cumprod``` to see if the result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what 'n' is supposed to be doing (is it always = 1,000,000?), but it's pretty straightforward to match your results above with cumprod:

```
In [60]: df.xx.cumprod() * 1e6

Out[60]: 0    1000000.000000
         1    1000000.000000
         2    1004878.000000
         3    1004878.000000
         4    1048483.675932
```