# Clip value of cumprod during calculation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Say I have the following dataframe

```py
x = pd.DataFrame({'value': [1.0, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.0, 0.9, 1.9, 1.7, 0.8, 0.5, 0.3]})
```

and I want to calculate the cumulative product without the value ever going below `1.0` or above `3.0`.

If I simply do the cumulative product (`x.cumprod()`), I end up with

```
       value
0   1.000000
1   1.100000
2   1.210000
3   1.331000
4   1.597200
5   1.597200
6   1.437480
7   2.731212
8   4.643060
9   3.714448
10  1.857224
11  0.557167
```

But what I would like to do is something like this

```py
def mycumprod(series, start, low, high):
    values = []
    last_value = start
    for value in series.values:
        last_value = last_value * value
        if last_value < low:
            last_value = low
        elif last_value > high:
            last_value = high
        values.append(last_value)
    return pd.Series(values)
```

where, during the cumulative product I prevent the value from ever going below `low` or above `high`.

Calling `mycumprod(x['value'], 1.0, 1.0, 3.0)` leads to the following series

```
0     1.000000
1     1.100000
2     1.210000
3     1.331000
4     1.597200
5     1.597200
6     1.437480
7     2.731212
8     3.000000
9     2.400000
10    1.200000
11    1.000000
dtype: float64
```

Is there a way to do this efficiently in Pandas?

I used [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25701494/pandas-cumsum-with-conditional-product-of-lagged-value) for cumsum in the past, but I don't know how to apply it to cumprod.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Does mycumprod produce the correct result? Why is the second element 1.21, shouldn't it be 1*1.1 = 1.1?

Comment: @timgeb good point, fixed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This type of cacluation is very difficult / impossible to vectorize using pandas/numpy, but you could use [`numba`](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html):

```
@njit
def mycumprod_numba(values, start, low, high):
    products = np.empty_like(values)
    last_value = start
    for i in range(len(values)):
        last_value *= values[i]
        if last_value < low:
            last_value = low
        elif last_value > high:
            last_value = high
        products[i] = last_value
    return products
```

For 1000 elements (`pd.DataFrame({'value': np.random.rand(1_000) * 2})`) I get a speed-up of about 15x:

```
%timeit mycumprod(x['value'], 1.0, 1.0, 3.0)
# 534 µs ± 6.34 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit pd.Series(mycumprod_numba(x['value'].to_numpy(), 1.0, 1.0, 3.0))
# 36.7 µs ± 630 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: When you say 15x, your timing includes the "warm-up" time of the function that has to be compiled, which is great because that means subsequent calls to `mycumprod_numba` should be even faster.

Comment: @Guimoute yes, but with averaging over the multiple runs in `timeit` I guess this is negligible

Comment: Good point. I can't test right now because my numba version is too low, but for version >= 0.54 it now support `np.clip`, if you want to benchmark multiple ifs against `last_value = np.clip(last_value, low, high)`.

Comment: @Guimoute: this doesn't work, see https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/3469, besides I think `clip` can't be faster (for a scalar) than two simple `if`s.

Comment: I was reading this https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/3465 and thought they also added support for scalars. My bad!